# Permissions and File.renameTo in Java 6 strange behavior

Tags: java, ubuntu, permissions

I have a Java program (running under Java 6), that monitors a directory parses the name of found files and runs actions (including copying the file) according to meta data and file content then, depending on the success or failure of the process, moves the files to a OK or KO directory.

I run my program as a simple user.
I tried, for the test, to put files belonging to root in my monitored directory.
Furthermore, I gave them 000 permissions.

The program would find the files but fail on the copy of the file.
For the record, the actual copy is done on this model:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputstrem(DestFile)
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(File);
byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
int nbRead;
while (-1 != (nbRead = fin.read(buffer)))
  fos.write(buffer, 0, nbRead);
```

So far, seeing the program fail is exactly what I expected, 000 permissions on a un-owned file, that cannot be read.

But what is strange is that my files were moved to the KO box.
The move is done with

```
File failedFileName = new File(KOdirectory, myFile.getName());
myFile.renameTo(failedFileName);
```

Should that work? (given they are onwed by root and with 000 permissions)?

They end up in the KO directory, still owned by root with 000 permissions.

When I add read permissions (so my files are 444 root-owned) and reinject them into the monitored folder, the whole process runs smoothly and files end up in the OK directory (still root-owned and 444 permissions).

How is it possible to move files on which one has only reading rights?
How does this reading, moving, deleting works depending on the OS? on the distro?

Maybe I should add I run this on Ubuntu whose awkward root user (it exists, but not completely) concept might be messing with this.

Comment: So after a bit of testing, I found out that: you can move 000 files if they are in a folder that you have read/write access to and you are moving them into a folder that you have read/write access to.

Comment: I would check this hasn't been fixed in Java 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving and renaming files does nothing to the file contents; instead, it changes the directory entries. So you need write permission on the directory, not the file itself.

Try it: if you remove the write permission to the directory, and give write permission to the file, you won't be able to rename or move the file anymore.

There are commands like mv or rm that actually check the file permission, and ask for confirmation if you want to move or change them. But that's extra code in the command and does not come from the operating system itself.

This is the same on all linux/unix systems. Reading/changing a file's content checks the permissions on the file; changing the file name or moving it to a different directory checks the permissions on the directory(/ies). This does not depend on the distro, it's the same on all linux systems, as well as Solaris, AIX, HP/UX and what other commercial unixes there are.

Answer (score 1):

Moving a file from one directory to another only requires modification of directory entries for the directories in question. This means that you need only write and search permissions to the directories. The permissions or the owner of the file being moved do not matter.

You can read more about this in the appropriate man pages, such as the page for [`rename(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) and [`path_resolution(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).

Answer (score 1):

A file has permission and this determines if you can read, modify or execute this file.

A file exists in one or more directories and it is the permission of the directory, not the file, which determines if the directory can be listed, modified or used.

So when you move a file, you are changing the directory, not the file.